# Read, write and access data in Firebase database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a basic database for an app to be used by students. I want the students to be able to logon with pre-defined user Ids (4 digit numbers) and a password (3 letters).... I've created this in Firebase.

I have tried many combinations and I just can't figure out how I would do the following:

1. check if a user with id exists (e.g. "1544")
2. If this user's password is "rql"
3. How to add a new user programatically
4. How to remove a user if found.

Any help in how to do this will be greatly appreciated. I've attached a screenshot of the sample of my DB. Thank you.

[image: db structure]

EDIT: UPDATE.... figured it out! Can check for corresponding pw for entered userID:

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rd1.isChecked()) { //logging on as staff successfully takes you to staff main screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainStaff.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (rd2.isChecked()) {//logging on as student successfully takes you to quiz screen
                //set up mref to get get the password for username entered
                DatabaseReference mref = mDatabase.child("student_users").child(e_uname.getText().toString())
                        .child("password");
                mref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //if password entered matches the username entered, allow access to quiz
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals(e_pwd.getText().toString())) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully logged on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainQuiz.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check UserID and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Flagged: too broad. Have you read the documentation? This is pretty damn explicitly defined in the firebase documentation. What have you tried? We aren't going to write your code for you.


https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Comment: Yes I did read the documentation but most of what I could find was in JS. Anyway as usual, always figure out the answer when you ask others for help. I've edited the above with solution